# How much protection does sandbox software provide against malicious .exe?

Tags: malware, sandbox, code-execution

I need to review a large number of .exe game files. I recently had an incident where I got infected by an .exe that passed all my 'checks': virus scan, Virustotal, reviews, community feedback, uploader history, uploader motive.

Lacking any other ideas, sandbox software seems like a viable second defence to those checks. I was wondering if I was running an infected .exe if I would be safe from infection, or rather what degree of safety a sandbox software offers in these instances.

Comment: Have you seen the online sandboxes? You can upload the binaries there to be tested without any risk to your systems.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "it depends on the sandbox". Sandboxing is not a binary state. Every bit of code that isn't running in supervisor (ring 0) (or hypervisor/ring -1, where relevant) on the processor could be described as at least a little "sandboxed". User-mode admin code is a little sandboxed, user-mode non-admin code moreso, user-mode code running with specifically restricted permissions is what is most often meant by "sandboxed", but you can definitely get more restrictive still.

Lots of apps are distributed with sandboxes (for example, stuff from the Windows or Apple app stores are generally more sandboxed than apps simply downloaded from the web, although not necessarily *very* tightly sandboxed). If you want to be able to run arbitrary code, though, that obviously won't work. You could in theory package your games up in app-style sandboxes based on what capabilities you expect the processes to need - very little write access, some more read access, maybe certain network privileges, etc. - but this is a hassle and you risk the games not working because you failed to give them access to something they legitimately need. Also, app sandboxes aren't the most fine-grained things out there (most of them allow all network traffic, network client traffic only, or no network traffic, for example; if you want to block specific ports or something you'll need to use a different sandboxing system or just configure your firewall).

Your best bet is probably a fairly strict container, a VM, or a throw-away system. VMs are quite secure (at least, if you don't turn on "integration" features), but are harder to get data out of and also make it harder to run a lot of games (restricted access to the hardware). The hardware issue can be fixed by using a computer with nothing you care about on it - a throw-away setup - but those are more hassle to "reset" between tests (VMs can be simply rolled back). Containers (on supported platforms) can be made quite strict, though they're less inherently secure (they still talk to the same kernel as unsandboxed processes, so local EoP vulns can be used for sandbox escapes).

---

With all that said, *in theory* a properly-designed sandbox will provide adequate protection against anything a malicious program might do. "Properly designed" is doing a lot of work there, though; speaking as somebody who has found sandbox escapes both professionally and as a hobby, they're really hard to get right. Also, most sandboxes are going to struggle at least somewhat against really novel attacks. A large part of why Meltdown and Spectre were such a big deal is because they broke a *lot* of sandboxes (VMs, low-privilege processes, Javascript sandboxes, etc.).

It can also be a delicate balancing act to trade off security with functionality. A sandbox will sometimes limit the compute resources (CPU time, RAM, etc.) that a process can access, to prevent it from consuming all the computer's resources and effectively attacking every other process on the machine, but this is obviously incompatible with properly testing a game that really demands everything your machine has and will perform badly if it has to share compute resources.